# Elasticsearch: Is it possible to query for a term facet that contains more than a term

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

Part of my mapping looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  INFO_NODO: {
    properties: {
      CODIGO: {
        type: string
      }
      ESTADO: {
        type: string
      }
      IN_HOME: {
        type: string
      }
      TEXTO: {
        type: string
      }
      ID_NODO: {
        type: integer
      }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I need to make a facet that will return the fields: `ID_NODO`, `TEXTO`, `IN_HOME`, `ESTADO`, `CODIGO`, and `COUNT` to parse it and feed it to my application. The key is that all these fields except `COUNT` are dependant on the `ID_NODO`, that is, if the field `INFO_NODO` is the same the rest of the information is the same... with that being said ideally I would like to make my facet dependent on the whole `INFO_NODO` field and not its sub-fields.
I found several solutions but I keep either failing to implement them properly or they are just not working. Any thoughts on my weird situation?

EDIT: What I'd need to do is:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "FACET_X_NODO": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "INFO_NODO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just can't get the syntax in no documentation since `INFO_NODO` is a subdocument and not a field.

Comment: You should look into script fields, you can combine all sub fields to make a key so your counts will aggregate on a collection of fields instead of just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "info_node_facet" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script_field" : "_source.INFO_NODO.CODIGO + _source.INFO_NODO.ESTADO",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work exactly as you put it since It wasn't letting me reference with the script_field a sub-field, however I took a long shot and tried this: {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "info_node_facet": {
      "terms": {
        "script_field": "_source.INFO_NODO",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}

And this worked exactly as I needed it to.
Thanks a lot!